# Split string by chars in python with re

Tags: python, regex

I have a set of strings in which numbers can be separated by different characters, or letters:

```
12
14:45:09
2;32
04:43
434.34
43M 343ho
```

I want to get a list of these numbers for each row:

```py
[12]
[14, 45, 9]
[2, 32]
[4, 43]
[434, 34]
[43, 343]
```

I try to do so, but this does not work:

```py
>>> import re
>>> pattern = r'(\d*)'
>>> re.split(pattern, '12')
['', '12', '', '', '']
>>> re.split(pattern, '14:45:09')
['', '14', '', '', ':', '45', '', '', ':', '09', '', '', '']
>>> pattern = r'([0-9]*)'
>>> re.split(pattern, '14:45:09')
['', '14', '', '', ':', '45', '', '', ':', '09', '', '', '']
>>> re.split(pattern, '43M 343ho')
['', '43', '', '', 'M', '', ' ', '343', '', '', 'h', '', 'o', '', '']
>>>
```

How can this be done correctly?

Comment: `re.split(r'\D+',s)`

Comment: Instead of `re.split` you can use `re.findall(r'\d+', line)`

Comment: Why does `343ho` give 34?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of split you might use [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) matching 0+ times a zero and capture 1+ digits

```
0*(\d+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2JDfc9/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/o0mApt)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"0*(\d+)"

strings = [
    "12",
    "14:45:09",
    "2;32",
    "04:43",
    "434.34",
    "43M 343ho"
]

for s in strings:
    print(re.findall(regex, s))
```

Output

```
['12']
['14', '45', '9']
['2', '32']
['4', '43']
['434', '34']
['43', '343']
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
from sys import stdin
import re

for line in stdin:
    result  = [int(x) for x in re.split(r'\D+',line) if x]
    print(result)
```

https://ideone.com/izR1BV

or

```py
    result  = [int(x) for x in re.findall(r'\d+',line)]
```

https://ideone.com/NQzQ72

Answer (score 0):

With string split:

"14:45:09".split(':')
The argument to split is the character on which to split.

With re:
re.split(r':', "14:45:09")